# How I could check connectivity in shell using an oneliner command without using netcat?

Tags: bash, docker, php, netcat

In a docker image I want to avoid installing netcat in order to ping for db connectivity at my entrypoint script:

```
/bin/sh

MOODLE_DB_HOST="xxxx"
MOODLE_DB_PORT=80

function pingdb {
    OK=0
    for count in {1..100}; do
      echo "Pinging database attempt ${count} into ${MOODLE_DB_HOST}:${MOODLE_DB_PORT}" 
      if  $(nc -z ${MOODLE_DB_HOST} ${MOODLE_DB_PORT}) ; then
        echo "Can connect into database"
        OK=1
        break
      fi
      sleep 5
    done

    echo "Is ok? "$OK

    if [ $OK -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Database type: "${MOODLE_DB_TYPE}
      echo "DB Type: "${MOODLE_DB_TYPE}
    else
      echo >&2 "Can't connect into database"
      exit 1
    fi
}
```

But instead, I want to use a `nc` replacement for entrypoint script running upon docker images utilising php.

Is there an alternative?

The reason why I want to do this is because I have 2 Dockerfiles, one debian-based and one alpine based:

debian-based php image:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION="7.4"
FROM  php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm as base

RUN --mount=type=bind,from=mlocati/php-extension-installer:latest,source=/usr/bin/install-php-extensions,target=/usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions \
    /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions xmlrpc mbstring zip xml intl soap gd opcache &&\
    echo "PHP_EXTENTION_DIR="$(php -i | grep extension_dir  | cut -d " " -f 5) >> /etc/environment &&\
    cat /etc/environment &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y netcat &&\
    apt-get autopurge -y &&\
    apt-get autoremove -y &&\
    apt-get autoclean &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* cache/* /var/lib/log/* &&\
    echo "max_input_vars=5000" > ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/moodle.ini

COPY ./scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And alpine-based:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION="7.4"
FROM  php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine as base

RUN --mount=type=bind,from=mlocati/php-extension-installer:latest,source=/usr/bin/install-php-extensions,target=/usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions \
    /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions xmlrpc mbstring zip xml intl soap gd opcache &&\
    apk update &&\
    apk add netcat-openbsd &&\
     rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /var/tmp/* cache/* /var/lib/log/* &&\
    echo "max_input_vars=5000" > ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/moodle.ini

COPY ./scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And sometimes depending the argument of `PHP_VERSION` may or may not the package for installing netcat do exist (or exist with different names). Also `apk add` and `apt-get` increases the build times significally as well.

So is there an alternative approach?

Comment: "_I want to avoid installing netcat_" - do you have `perl`, `python`, `php`, `telnet`, `socat`, `timeout`, and/or `bash`? Please tell us (in your question)

Comment: The reason why is because in my case I will add extra layer or the netcat package name is named differently in different images. By doing so I slighly reduce the size and docker build time.

Comment: Also tese options may not shipped with a Docker image so using the existing lang is prefferable compared to normal linux distro.

Comment: Please put updates in your question. Not here in the comments

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is:

```
function pingdb {
    OK=0
    for i in $(seq 1 100); do
      echo "Pinging database attempt ${count} into ${MOODLE_DB_HOST}:${MOODLE_DB_PORT}" 
      if  $(php -r "is_resource(@fsockopen(\"${MOODLE_DB_HOST}\",intval(\"${MOODLE_DB_PORT}\")))?exit(0):exit(1);") ; then
        echo "Can connect into database"
        OK=1
        break
      fi
      sleep 5
    done


    if [ $OK -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Database type: "${MOODLE_DB_TYPE}
      echo "DB Type: "${MOODLE_DB_TYPE}
    else
      echo >&2 "Can't connect into database"
      exit 1
    fi
}
```

As you can see the `nc` is replaced like this:

```
php -r "is_resource(@fsockopen(\"${MOODLE_DB_HOST}\",intval(\"${MOODLE_DB_PORT}\")))?exit(0):exit(1);"
```

The `fsockopen` takes 2 params:

- `host`
- `port`

What I do is try to open a socket in php and check if socket is oppened. If yes then I exit with `0` status code else I exit with `1`. Each param is passed using a string that comes from shell script thus I encode the `"` characters using `\` in order to convert the values into php strings.

Without using vars you can do it:

```
php -r "is_resource(@fsockopen(\"google.com",80)))?exit(0):exit(1);"
```

But in order to b safe I used intval at version using bash params.

Comment: Wouldn't this require you to have `php` installed though? What's the point of avoiding installing a standard tool like `nc` if you still need to install `php`? Wouldn't it make more sense to use things that are commonly found on *nix systems like bash itself, or perl or python etc?

Comment: In my case, I already have installed php in my docker image (I use docker php images) but I do not have netcat and installing it increases build time (because of package cache cleanups at `docker build` after I install netcat in my `Dockerfile`)

Comment: OK. Might be worth adding that to the question then since using php for something like this is just weird unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @terdon, not sure I'd call netcat "standard"... Not just because it's not POSIX, but because there are multiple implementations of it with slightly different options. PHP might actually be better in that sense, since (AFAIK?) there's only one implementation, so if you have it, you know what you have. Of course Perl or just Bash might be even more likely to be available.

Comment: @ilkkachu fair, by "standard" I just meant "likely to be present on a nix system".